# Vertical menu with images: align the first character of the items

Tags: css

I have a vertical menu. I would like to align vertically the name of the of items. I have this:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/car95.svg" />
      <span>Cars</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/restaurant95.svg" />
      <span>Restaurants</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The result is like this:

[image]

but I want this:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/o404phzt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the image in a fixed-width `div`:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/car95.svg" />
      </div>
      <span>Cars</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="menu-item">
        <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/restaurant95.svg" />
      </div>
      <span>Restaurants</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because that would stretch the image.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to create a 2x2 table and not using lists.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/car95.svg" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Cars</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/restaurant95.svg" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>Restaurants</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can still use classes inside the td tag as needed. (aligning for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS tables:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
}
ul > li {
  display: table-row;
}
ul > li > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/car95.svg" />
    <span>Cars</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/restaurant95.svg" />
    <span>Restaurants</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note I removed the links because they interfere with the layout.

However, since you use `<a href="#">`, you are probably handling them with JS. Then, you can just remove them, do the same click handling with JS, and fake links with CSS:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
}
ul > li {
  display: table-row;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul > li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
ul > li > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/car95.svg" />
    <span>Cars</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/restaurant95.svg" />
    <span>Restaurants</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice! However in this case it's no longer links.

Comment: @Oriol is kinda the same i tried. Align second img in the middle of first and is ok :)

Comment: @Oriol thanks, your solution is maybe more professinal or robust, but I finally used the DanielGibbs answer. Since Im not using JS for my links, I found your solution a bit complicated.

Comment: @ziiweb Oh, so my guess was wrong. But why do you use `<a href="#">`, if you don't handle it with JS?

Comment: @Oriol it just was a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Structuring the image and `span`s inside `inline-block` `div`s will solve this flexibly:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li {
  width: 300px;
}
li div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.image {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/car95.svg" />
      </div>
      <div class="link">
        <span>Cars</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://sermovi.es/images/restaurant95.svg" />
      </div>
      <div class="link">
        <span>Restaurants</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91ouzjpp/1/)